# Regex Pattern for filter out anything that doesn't Match

Tags: c#, .net, regex, regex-negation

Using `Regex.Replace(mystring, @"[^MV:0-9]", "")` will remove any Letters that are not `M`,`V`,`:`, or 0-9 (\d could also be used) the problem is I want to remove anything that is not `MV:` then numbers.

I need to replace anything that is not this pattern with nothing:

```
Starting String                        | Wanted Result
---------------------------------------------------------
sdhfuiosdhusdhMV:1234567890sdfahuosdho | MV:1234567890
MV:2138911230989hdsafh89ash32893h8u098 | MV:2138911230989
809308ej0efj0934jf0934jf4fj84j8904jf09 | Null
123MV:1234321234mnnnio234324234njiojh3 | MV:1234321234
mdfmsdfuiovvvajio123oij213432ofjoi32mm | Null
```

But what I get with what I have is:

```
Starting String                        | Returned Result
---------------------------------------------------------
sdhfuiosdhusdhMV:1234567890sdfahuosdho | MV:1234567890
MV:2138911230989hdsafh89ash32893h8u098 | MV:213891123098989328938098
809308ej0efj0934jf0934jf4fj84j8904jf09 | 809308009340934484890409
123MV:1234321234mnnnio234324234njiojh3 | 123MV:12343212342343242343
mdfmsdfuiovvvajio123oij213432ofjoi32mm | mmvvv1232134232mm
```

And even if there is a Regex pattern for this would I be better off using something along the lines of:

```
if (Regex.IsMatch(strMyString, @"MV:"))
{
    string[] strarMyString = Regex.Split(strMyString, @"MV:");
    string[] strarNumbersAfterMV = Regex.Split(strarMyString[1], @"[^\d]");
    string WhatIWant = strarNumbersAfterMV[0]
}
```

If I went with the Latter option would there be away to have:

```
        string[] strarNumbersAfterMV = Regex.Split(strarMyString[1], @"[^\d]");
```

Only make one split at the first change from numbers? (It will always start with number following the `MV:`)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Can't you just do:

```
string matchedText = null;
var match = Regex.Match(myString, @"MV:[0-9]+");
if (match.Success)
{
    matchedText = Value;
}
Console.WriteLine((matchedText == null) ? "Not found" : matchedText);
```

That should give you exactly what you need.

Comment: That would be great if i Wanted to know if the string Contained the Pattern or not but I don't see how that helps me negate everything else.

Comment: @user2140261: You could just... not use the rest? Seeing as that only matches your requirements, you just access the match and.. use it for whatever it is you need it for.

Comment: @user2140261: see my updated answer. You just need to get the value from the returned `Match` object.

Comment: Wow! I had no idea the the RegEx.Match even returned a Value or Success element. Nice to know. Also that it returned Index, Groups, Capture, Length. Thank you VERY much.

Comment: Documentation is a wonderful thing. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6f7hht7k.aspx